# How can I re-insert the values on a form, after a user clicks to edit something?

Tags: meteor

I have a **single** template that's wired up to show a post if the current user has a post in the collection. If not, it automatically shows a form.

Now I want to add an EDIT functionality. When the user clicks on the Edit button, it

1. Saves the post text in a variable.
2. Deletes the post from the collection, thus the template reactively reveals the form again.

Up to this part it all works. **How can I then add the text that I just saved in a variable, into the "input" element of the form?**

jQuery works for this on the console, but I don't know where to put it in my code.

On Discover Meteor, they use the Router to set the context. I'd like to try my idea with jQuery, if possible. 
Thank you. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep your post in a session variable and in the `edit` click handler, set the session variable to the one you're currently viewing.

In the form inputs, you can set the `value` attributes to their corresponding post values.

ex: `<input name="title" value="{{post.title}}" />`

and in your template helper

```
Template.form.helpers({ 
    post: function() { 
       return Session.get('post')
    }
})
```